# How to send email IF Cell Value Contains Certain Text?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having problems with a script that I wrote. It isn't throwing any errors however I am not receiving the emails. The goal of this script is to send an email if column G has value Y.

```
Column A = Organization Name
Column C= Days Aging
Column F= Email (where the email should be sent)
Column G= Status (where the Y will be)        



    function CheckPastDueAccounting() {
          //Fetch Accounting Spreadsheet with past due accounts

           var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
           var lrow= ss.getLastRow(); 
           for(var i=2;i<=lrow;i++);

           var Status =ss.getRange(i,7);
           var value = Status.getValue();
           if (value == 'Y') {

            var DaysAgingColumn = ss.getRange(i,3); 
            var DaysAging = DaysAgingColumn.getValue();


            // Fetch Organization Name
            var Organizations = ss.getRange(i,1); 
            var org = Organizations.getValue();


            // Fetch the email address
            var emailRange = ss.getRange(i,6);
            var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

            // Send Alert Email.
            var message = 'Hi. Your account is past due ' + DaysAging + ' days.'; // Second column
            var subject = 'Past Due Accounting Alert: ' + org;

            GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

             }

        }
```

Comment: In your question, you say `The goal of this script is to send an email if column G has the word YES.`. But in your script, `if (value == 'Y') {` is used. How about this?

Comment: Use `console.log` or `Logger.log` to add logs to your script for a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: @Tanaike just worded that poorly! I think the script reflects the Y value correctly. Any recommendations?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you post it as an answer, it might be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You should be enclosing the statements you want to run in loop between `{ }`. Otherwise, the for loop is just incrementing the variable `i` and not running any of your desired code.

Moreover, after the for loop ends, the variable `i` is higher than the last row with content (`lrow`) which means that all calls to `.getRange(i, columnIndex)` refer to empty cells. Because of this, no email is sent, and no error is shown.

#### Solution:

```js
function CheckPastDueAccounting() {
  // Code before for loop starts
  for(var i=2; i<=lrow; i++) {
    // Code to run in loop (iterate through all rows with content)
  }
  // Code to run after for loop ends
}
```

#### Improving code:

Calling [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) for individual cells, for each row in a `for` loop, is not the best way to iterate through rows with data.

It's much better to first (1) get all the values in the desired range, with [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), and then (2) iterate through the resulting 2D array, like this:

```js
function CheckPastDueAccounting() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lrow= ss.getLastRow();
  var firstRow = 2;
  var values = ss.getRange(firstRow, 1, lrow - firstRow + 1, 7).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var value = row[6];    
    if (value == 'Y') {
      var DaysAging = row[2];            
      var org = row[0]; // Fetch Organization Name          
      var emailAddress = row[5]; // Fetch the email address      
      var message = 'Hi. Your account is past due ' + DaysAging + ' days.';
      var subject = 'Past Due Accounting Alert: ' + org;    
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); // Send Alert Email.   
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))